# Is the docs of the cnosdb wrong?

Tags: cnosdb

```
There are two types of admin permissons:

Initial admin permission
Admin permission granted
Note:

> Support people who have admin permissions to grant admin permissions to others.
> Whether the is_admin field in the system table cluster_schema.users has admin permissions(both initial and granted).
> If granted_admin is set to true for user_options in the cluster_schema.users system table, the admin permission is granted.
> A person with admin permission can reclaim admin permission granted to someone else.
The initial admin permission cannot be reclaimed (that is, the admin permission of the root user).
```

but when I wanna change the root's 'grand_admin' field, it can execute successfully. So is it a bug or it is just a wrong description in documents.